# Postgresql put method json body I get error json parsing ,

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I'm getting this error:

> Unexpected token , in JSON at position 197
> at JSON.parse ()
> at parse (C:\Users\hp\empServers\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
> at C:\Users\hp\empServers\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:128:18
> at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)

This is my controller:

```js
app.post("/svr/employees", function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("Request Body:", req.body);
  let { empCode, name, department, designation, salary, gender } = req.body;
  if (
    !empCode ||
    !name ||
    !department ||
    !designation ||
    salary === undefined ||
    !gender
  ) {
    res.status(400).send("Invalid data. Please provide all required fields.");
    return;
  }
  const insertQuery =
    "INSERT INTO employee (empcode, name, department, designation, salary, gender) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)";
  const values = [empCode, name, department, designation, salary, gender];
  client.query(insertQuery, values, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error while inserting data:", err);
      res.status(500).send("An error occurred while inserting data.");
    } else {
      console.log(result);
      res.send(`${result.rowCount} insertion Successful`);
    }
  });
});
```

i have tried to check JSON body through console its not working  JSON body for insertion i will paste below i am using postman for testing api

```json
{
  "empcode": 1129,
  "name": "hafsdmbdfsd",
  "department": "Technology",
  "designation": "Mansdfsdfager",
  "salary": 657567,
  "gender": "Male"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

With the final comma your JSON is not valid. Try removing it first